# Decoupling Kafka from an Application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x, kafka-producer-api, modularity

I have an application that receives large amount of GET requests (around 250000 in 5 mins). The application parses the query params and publishes to Kafka. The code to publish is as follows:

```
public class KafkaProcessor {

  private static final String BATCH_SIZE = "batch.size";
  private static final String REQUEST_REQUIRED_ACKS = "request.required.acks";
  private static final String PRODUCER_TYPE = "producer.type";
  private static final String VALUE_SERIALIZER = "value.serializer";
  private static final String KEY_SERIALIZER = "key.serializer";
  private static final String METADATA_BROKER_LIST = "bootstrap.servers";
  private static final String MAX_BLOCK_MS = "max.block.ms";
  private static final String KAFKA_ENABLED = "enabled";

  private static Properties props = new Properties();
  private static KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
  private static ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord;
  private static String topic;


  static {
    boolean isEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(ResourceProps.INSTANCE.getKafkaProps(KAFKA_ENABLED));
    if (isEnabled) {
      //Setting up a producer configuration.
      props.put(METADATA_BROKER_LIST, "x.x.x.x:9092,y.y.y.y:9092");
      props.put(KEY_SERIALIZER, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
      props.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
      props.put(PRODUCER_TYPE, "async");
      props.put(REQUEST_REQUIRED_ACKS, "1");
      props.put(BATCH_SIZE, "1000");
      props.put(MAX_BLOCK_MS, "10000");
      producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
      topic = "pixel-server";
    }
  }


  private static void publishToKafka(JSONObject data) {
      producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, data.toString());
      producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback() {
        @Override public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception exception) {
          if (exception != null) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

My application is hosted in an AWS instance. The Kafka server is also in another AWS machine.

However, if the kafka is down or if kafka is slow to respond due to any reason then my application freezes and cannot process any request further. I want to know how can I make my application independent of Kafka, meaning, if the kafka goes down (or is slow to respond) then it should not affect my application.

I tried couple of ways like if the kafka gives a timeout then count the number of timeout exception and stop publishing to kafka but since the volume of request is very huge so by the time, I get any timeout exception, my application freezes.

Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

I am using Kafka 0.8.2. My server is in Vertx. The OS used in Ubuntu. The ulimit are set to max.

Comment: I don't have experience with it but I think you will need a [kafka cluster](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion) with data [mirrored](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker) between the nodes.

Comment: You might want to look at something like Akka Streams for Kafka or at the very least have an independent Thread for the Kafka client actions

Comment: I dont know about Akka Streams (will look into it) but spawning a new thread to publish data to kafka is choking the system. The incoming request are too huge and spawning thread for each request simply chokes the system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have three or more nodes in your Kafka cluster (which is vital for any high-loaded application), you could try some tricks:

1. Try to set `acks` producer config to `0`. This will affect the consistency of your application (some messages can be dropped on producer side and will be lost forever). Documentation says:

   > If set to zero then the producer will not wait for any acknowledgment from the server at all. The record will be immediately added to the socket buffer and considered sent. No guarantee can be made that the server has received the record in this case
2. Set `max.block.ms` producer config to `0`. This will cause your application to immediately throw TimeoutException on each send to Kafka cluster without any blocking, *but only on memory buffer overflow*. **Note that it affects only client-side blocking, not network calls!**
3. Reduce `request.timeout.ms` to small values (like `10` or `100`). This will cause Kafka client to throw TimeoutException on any network operation that takes time longer than `request.timeout.ms`.

And some more advices:

1. update your Kafka instances to recent versions to get more stable cluster;
2. to be high-available, your Kafka cluster has to contain at least three nodes (and always odd number of nodes to avoid [split-brain condition](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/split-brain-a-ka-network-partition-e331e3caf036))
3. you should try to play with `max.batch.size` and `linger.ms` producer configs to reach optimal latency-throughput ratio for your application

Comment: Couple of additional ideas taken from http://ingest.tips/2015/07/19/tips-for-improving-performance-of-kafka-producer/

- Increase batch.size to reduce number of calls and more records per producer call.

- use produceAsync to completely isolate the two processes.